# Making certain pictures visible depending on input?

Tags: c#, winforms, visible

If the user's input is less than 10, I want to display pic1 & if it's greater than or equal to 10, I want to display pic2.
At the moment both Visible properties of pic1 and pic2 are set to false to hide them from the user before the input is entered.

My following code doesn't seem to work:

```
        if (userInput < 10)
        {
            pic1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pic2.Visible = true;
        }
```

Should I even be using the visible property?

Comment: This question is tagged wrongly and you should mention in the question what you are using to display pictures (I assume either winforms or WPF)

Comment: Windows Forms Application

Comment: Do you *mean* to set it **true** - *without* a corresponding **false** - in both cases? It should probably look like: `pic1.Visible = userInput < 10; pic2.Visible = !pic1.Visible;` (or modified for exact goal; the point is to update *both* Visible properties to the current desired state).

Comment: @ClaudioPietrantonio When run once it will set both Visible. One should probably be made invisible.

Comment: Clearly a job for the...debugger.  What is the value of userInput when that line gets hit?  Put a debug stop on that line and examine it when you run the program.

Answer (score 1):

What about this simple code?

```
if (userInput < 10)
{
   pic1.Visible = true;
   pic2.Visible = false;
}
else
{
   pic2.Visible = true;
   pic1.Visible = false;
}
```

**UPDATE** 
But the best solution gave you @user2864740 in comments